# How to Special price based on attribute?

Tags: attributes, price, special-price

Is it possible to set special price automatically based on a attribute?

I have an attribute called `offerprice` in which I enter the percentage of discount.

So if the product price is **$100** and I enter **10** in the `offerprice` field, the special price would automatically be calculated to **$90**

Answer (score 0):

You can create cart price rule based on Attribute. You have create and assign attribute to product.

Attribute Type Yes/No. Based on that attribute value you can create cart price rule and set condition.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but I need to show the discounted special price along with the regular price in the catalog listing and detail pages. That is why I'm going this way

Answer (score 0):

In this case, You can do some customisation based on that attribute. You have to set Special price also and need to override/customise getFinalPrice() function.

In that function you can check that attribute's value is yes then workflow as it is. If that attribute's value us no then getFinalPrice() == getActualPrice() and. return finalPrice.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of some tutorial or the file path?
I'm new to magento development

Comment: I don't have any document for this. But you can customise as I suggested.